# How to collect profiler data from .NET app

Tags: .net, profiling

I have a Windows service that regularly launches .NET console applications as external processes.

I want to collect profiling data (CPU) from those externally launched processes while the service operates and analyze it later - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. One option would be to use [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) to collect a system wise trace. I assume you control launching the console apps, so you could modify the launching to capture the trace on start.

You can configure PerfView to capture all sorts of details to help you troubleshoot what is going on. If you haven't already added ETW to your application I suggest you [take a look at that](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx) as well, as it will help you zoom in on what your application is doing and how long it takes.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I have little .NET experience - do I need to add anything to the code of the external processes that makes them emit ETW logs, so PerfView can analyze them? I'm really only interested in method call times.

Comment: PerfView can sample call stacks, so you don't have to add anything. However, adding ETW events will make it easier for you to identify which part of the application is running at any given point (without looking at call stacks).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Will mark the answer as correct when I have found that it works.